# Improvement of a bash script to make some basic statistics on files

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I have some files like this:

- file_1

  ```
  chrV    20924149
  chrX    17718866
  chrIV   17493793
  chrII   15279345
  chrI    15072423
  chrIII  13783700
  chrM    13794
  ```
- file_2

  ```
  chrI    230218
  chrII   813184
  chrIII  316620
  chrIV   1531933
  chrIX   439888
  chrM    85779
  chrV    576874
  chrVI   270161
  chrVII  1090940
  chrVIII 562643
  chrX    745751
  chrXI   666816
  chrXII  1078177
  chrXIII 924431
  chrXIV  784333
  chrXV   1091291
  chrXVI  948066
  ```

And I need to get the mean and the total values from column 2 and the max and min values from the files. I got some ideas from stackoverflow and made this ugly bash script.

```
#!usr/bin/env bash


for VARIABLE in Data/*.sizes
do
    echo $VARIABLE
    echo  'Genome length:'
    awk -F '\t' '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }' $VARIABLE
    echo 'Chr number:'
    awk -F '\t' '{ NR $1 } END { print NR }' $VARIABLE
    echo 'Chr mean length:'
    awk -F '\t' '{ total += $2 } END { print total/NR }' $VARIABLE
    echo 'Longest Chr:'
    awk -v max=0 '{if($2>max){want=$1" "$2; max=$2}}END{print want}' $VARIABLE
    echo 'Smallest Chr:'
    awk 'NR == 1 || $2 < min {line = $1; min = $2}END{print line " " min}' $VARIABLE
    echo " "
done
```

It worked but if you have any better ideas and maybe a way to make this more general, because time to time this is done in some similar files.

I would appreciate any inputs because I don't usually use `awk` and `bash`.

I got this printed out:

```
Data/file_1
Genome length:
100286070
Chr number:
7
Chr mean length:
1.43266e+07
Longest Chr:
chrV 20924149
Smallest Chr:
chrM 13794
```

Comment: If you need your code reviewed, the site for that is [codereview.se]

Comment: You should be using a single awk script for the body of the loop at least, not a bunch of individual awk scripts, and chances are you don't need the shell loop anyway and could just call awk with `Data/*.sizes` as the argument. I recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to use awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `awk` script will accomplish the task. I will write it as explicit `awk` program file because of the length - which is mainly due to the function to print the analysis results; the actual calculations are rather short:

#### If you have GNU `awk` for the `ENDFILE` block:

Program file (let's call it `analyze_genome_g.awk`):

```c
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

# Begin of file, characterized by FNR, the per-file line-counter, being 1.
# Initialize statistics: set sum, min, and max to first chromosome length
# and name of longest/shortest ('long'/'short') to first chromosome name.
FNR==1{s=min=max=$2; short=long=$1}

# All other lines: Update sum, min, and max lengths
FNR>1{s=s+$2;if (min>$2) {min=$2; short=$1}; if (max<$2) {max=$2; long=$1}}

# End-of-file (GNU awk feature!): Print statistics
ENDFILE{
    printf("%s\n",FILENAME);
    printf("- Genome length         : %d\n",s);
    printf("- Nr. of chromosomes    : %d\n",FNR);
    printf("- Mean chomosome length : %.1f\n",s/FNR);
    printf("- Shortest chromosome   : %s (length=%d)\n",short,min);
    printf("- Longest chromosome    : %s (length=%d)\n",long,max);
    printf("\n");
}
```

You can call it as

```
gawk -f analyze_genome_g.awk file_1 file_2 ...
```

Output:

```
file_1
- Genome length         : 100286070
- Nr. of chromosomes    : 7
- Mean chomosome length : 14326581.4
- Shortest chromosome   : chrM (length=13794)
- Longest chromosome    : chrV (length=20924149)

file_2
- Genome length         : 12157105
- Nr. of chromosomes    : 17
- Mean chomosome length : 715123.8
- Shortest chromosome   : chrM (length=85779)
- Longest chromosome    : chrIV (length=1531933)
```

#### Other `awk` variants:

If your `awk` doesn't know the `ENDFILE` condition, a little workaround is required - basically saving the file properties in temporary variables and print the statistics at either the beginning of a new file (for the previous file), or in the `END` block when the last file was processed.

To make this more convenient, we define a function `printstats()` which does the output.

Program file (`analyze_genome.awk`):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function printstats()
{
    printf("%s\n",last_fn);
    printf("- Genome length         : %d\n",s);
    printf("- Nr. of chromosomes    : %d\n",last_fnr);
    printf("- Mean chomosome length : %.1f\n",s/last_fnr);
    printf("- Shortest chromosome   : %s (length=%d)\n",short,min);
    printf("- Longest chromosome    : %s (length=%d)\n",long,max);
    printf("\n");
}

# Begin of file
# FNR==1 always works, but now we have to save file properties, too.
# If it is _not_ the first file (NR, the global line counter, is larger than
# FNR, the per-file line-counter), print statistics (of the previous file).
FNR==1{
    if (NR>1) printstats();
    s=min=max=$2; short=long=$1;
    last_fn=FILENAME; last_fnr=1;
}


FNR>1{
    s=s+$2; if (min>$2) {min=$2; short=$1}; if (max<$2) {max=$2; long=$1};
    last_fnr++;
}

END{printstats()}
```

You can call it similarly as

```
awk -f analyze_genome.awk file_1 file_2 ...
```

**As a general note**, using shell loops to process text files is [disrecommended as it is rather inefficient](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice); `awk` and the like can perform almost all text-processing tasks and many statistical calculations much faster.

Comment: AdminBee one of the best answers I have receive in a long time in any site of stackoverflow. I really really appreciate your time for a so nice answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PauloSergioSchlogl You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can produce your stat reports in a yaml fashion using the GNU version of the desk calculator. The below is a heavily commented version of the dc code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for VARIABLE in Data/*.sizes
do
    printf '%s:\n' "$VARIABLE" 
< "$VARIABLE" awk '{$1="["$1"]";sub(/^-/,"_",$2)}1' \
| dc -e "
[32adnn]si  # two-spaces indent in reporting
[
lix[Genome length:]   n32an lsp
lix[Chr number:]      n32an lkp
lix[Chr mean length:] n32an /1.0*p
lix[Longest Chr:]     n32an lM     n32an lmp
lix[Smallest Chr:]    n32an lN     n32an lnp
q
]sR
[dsmrdsMr]s+
[dsnrdsNr]s-
[
?z0=R  # report stats @ eof
lk1+sk # increment line kounter
dls+ss # update running sum
dlm<+  # update max
dln>-  # update min
cz0=?  # call myself recursively to read next line 
]s?
[
?       # read the first line
1skdss  # initialize knt, sum
dsmrdsM # initialize max
sNsn    # initialize min
cl?x    # read next line
]sI
lIx     # set the ball rolling, kinda like main() 
"
```

**Results:**

```
Data/file_1.sizes:
  Genome length: 100286070
  Chr number: 7
  Chr mean length: 14326581.0
  Longest Chr: chrV 20924149
  Smallest Chr: chrM 13794

Data/file_2.sizes:
  Genome length: 12157105
  Chr number: 17
  Chr mean length: 715123.0
  Longest Chr: chrIV 1531933
  Smallest Chr: chrM 85779
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesh. I really appreciate.

Answer (score -2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+$2}END{print sum/finalcountofline}' filename ====Mean

awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}($2 > sum){sum=$2}END{print sum}' filename ===Max

awk 'NR==1{sum=$2}($2 < sum){sum=$2}END{print sum}' filename ===min
```

Comment: Why do you divide by 74 for the mean? Should it it be like the OP has, and divide by NR? Also, using "sum" is a legal, but distracting variable name when you're using it as a min or max. I'd also encourage initializing "max" with the same NR==1 technique that you (and the OP) used for min.